# Date comparison and max in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I want to ask two questions about JPA:
What is wrong in my query(Offer.findHighestOffer) which is supposed to select max price from every offer linked to auction, is it correctly written?

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Offer.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM Offer o")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Offer.findById", query = "SELECT o FROM Offer o WHERE o.id = ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Offer.findHighestOffer", query = "SELECT o FROM Offer o WHERE o.auction.id = ?1 HAVING MAX(o.price)")
})
public class Offer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private double price;
    @ManyToOne
    private Auction auction;
    @ManyToOne
    private UserAccount user;
    private Timestamp creationDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

and can somebody tell me how to compare timestamp fields in jpql?

Here is my Auction entity

```
@Entity

@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Auction.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM Auction a WHERE a.id = ?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Auction.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Auction a"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Auction.findExpired", query = "SELECT a FROM Auction a WHERE a.expireDate < ?1"),
})
public class Auction implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private UserAccount user; //nie daje sie id tylko obiekt
    private String description;
    private String title;
    private double price;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "auction", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Offer> offers = new LinkedList<Offer>();
     private Timestamp creationDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
     private Timestamp expirationDate;
```

I have read something about passing current time as a parameter and I did so but it still crashes

```
Problem compiling [SELECT a FROM Auction a WHERE a.expireDate < ?1]. 
[30, 42] The state field path 'a.expireDate' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

and in my code it's used like this:

```
Offer highestOffer;
TypedQuery<Auction> auctionQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Auction.findExpired", Auction.class);
auctionQuery.setParameter(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace your query as below.

```
  @NamedQueries({
            @NamedQuery(name = "Auction.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM Auction a WHERE a.id = :id")
            @NamedQuery(name = "Auction.findExpired", query = "SELECT a FROM Auction a WHERE a.expireDate < :expireDate")
```

and set the parameter

```
 TypedQuery<Auction> auctionQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Auction.findExpired", Auction.class);
    auctionQuery.setParameter("expireDate", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Still the same error:
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT a FROM Auction a WHERE a.expireDate < :expir
Severe:   eDate].